# What is the order of execution between python code and javascript code in html

Tags: javascript, python, html, bottle

I am using bottle framework to dynamically list a link for editing a task, rows is a collection of tuple with multiple (id, task, status) logically the code below should give the first link

```
http://localhost:8217/edit/1
```

second link

```
http://localhost:8217/edit/2
```

so on and forth

but all the link are

```
http://localhost:8217/edit/5
```

therefore I suspect this has to do with the order the code is executed, any hint would be much appreciated

```
<p>The open items are as follows:</p>
<table border="1">
%for row in rows:
    <tr>
    %for col in row:
        <td>{{col}}</td>   
    %end
    <script language="javascript">
        var number = "http://localhost:8217/edit/";
        var key = {{row[0]}};
        console.log(key);
    </script>
    <td>
        <a href="" onClick="location.href=number +key;return false";>Editing</a> 
    </td>
    </tr>
%end
</table>
```

Comment: Read the generated source.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using javascript here?  Why not just use the template to populate the `href`s directly?

Comment: @ron.rothman can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python code runs on the **server**; Javascript code runs on the client.
Therefore, Javascript code can only run after the Python code finishes.

---

However, this has nothing to do with your problem.

HTML tags do not create local variable scopes; all of your rows share the same `key` variable.

By the time you click the link, `key` will always have the last value (since all of the JS has already executed).

You should build an `href` attribute in server-side code instead.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is in your javascript. It's not really a problem though, it's just the way the javascript event loop works. The short answer, is that when your browser is reading the rendered template, it loads the `onClick` events into the event queue, but doesn't actually call them. Only after it's done processing the page, does it start going through the event queue and reading them one-by-one. But at this point, all the `<script>` tags in your page have processed, and the current value of `key` will be the last value it had from the loop, presumably `5` in the examples you gave. As the browser handles the events from the event queue, it will just assign the current value of `key` to the `onClick` handle, which is why they all get the value 5.

One possible fix is to use a closure to take a "snapshot" of the current value of `key` as the script tags are read. To create the closure I will use a self-invoking function, but there are other ways to do this:

```
var key = (function() {
    return {{row[0]}};
)();
```

This is actually a very common problem, so you might want to look around for a more thorough explanation. A good starting point is the subsection "The infamous loop problem" here: [Javascript Scope and Closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

Comment: I do agree with the other commenters though. If you are fabricating a template in the server (and you're looping through the rows server-side anyway), why not just generate the attribute server-side too? Unless of course, you wont actually hard-code the number variable on your script tag, and will have the browser determine that...